# MERN Stack - Can't connect to MongoDB with URI string

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I cannot connect my MERN application to mongoDB with a URI string in a .env file. The error I am getting is

```
URI must include hostname, domain name, and tld
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

I am using a file called db.js (inside of a config folder):

```
const connectDB = async () => {
  try {
    await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGOURI, {
    });

    console.log(`MongoDB Connected...`);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
    // Exit process with failure
    process.exit(1);
  }
};

module.exports = connectDB;
```

Here is my .env file which is in the root folder:

```
PORT = 5000
MONGOURI =
    "mongodb+srv://<my_username_is_here>:<password_is_here>@gmttcluster.cvloz.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority"
```

I call this all from a script called server.js in the root directory

```
const express = require("express");
const colors = require("colors");
const dotenv = require("dotenv").config();
const { errorHandler } = require("./middleware/errorMiddleWare");
const connectDB = require("./config/db");
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

connectDB();

const app = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.use("/home", require("./routes/teeTimeRoutes"));

app.use(errorHandler);

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server started on port ${port}`));
```

Here is another error I get when I take the "" out of the .env file

```
Invalid scheme, expected connection string to start with "mongodb://" or "mongodb+srv://"
```

Comment: Does your password have special characters (ex  : / ? # [ ] @)?

Comment: It did, and then I changed the password to get rid of those special characters and I get the same error.

Comment: Have you confirmed your env file is working? Try logging the connection string before the call to `connect()`

Comment: When I tried to console.log(MONGOURI) it didn't log. It just is a blank line in the console log. When I log process.env.PORT I do get my port (5000) logged.

Answer (score 0):

Try logging some variables from your .env file, it could be a problem with your env file..

Comment: Hi, Welcome to Stack Overflow, Please read [How do I write good answers?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: When I tried to console.log(MONGOURI) it didn't log. It just is a blank line in the console log. When I log process.env.PORT I do get my port (5000) logged.

Comment: Try and remove the quotes "" from around the MONGOURI in the env file, plus make sure that MONGOURI = Your mongo uri are all on the same line in the env file. That may work.